# Negative Second Moment of Inverse Gamma Distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I am trying to solve the following:

$\int_0^\infty{x^{-2}p(x)}dx$

Where $p(x)$ is the inverse gamma pdf:

$p(x)=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}(1/x)^{\alpha+1} exp(-\beta/x) $

Numerically, I can see that the solution exists when I do Monte Carlo analysis over 100K scenarios, but I just don't have the mathematical background to solve the equation. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Try the substitution $u = x^{-1}$ and then refer to the definition of the gamma function $\Gamma$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Comment: You want the second positive moment [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: @a_student, the u substitution got me what I needed. Thanks for the helpful hint!